# prcomp leading to differing number of row

Tags: r, pca, cbind

When I try the code below, I get a different number of rows after running prcomp. I wonder why that might be?

```
VAS.pca <- prcomp(~., data=VAS, na.action=na.omit, center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE )
```

### To extract x values that represent principal component score for each observation

```
str(VAS.pca)

VAS.pca$x

VAS2 <- cbind(VAS, VAS.pca$x[,1:2])
```

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 146, 143
```

Comment: perhaps you had three `NA` in your original data? check `dim(na.omit(VAS))[2]` to see if it is 143

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it showed 143....Great help for a beginner. For PCA, would it be OK for me to replace NA with 0 for the principal component values?

Comment: Find out why your values are missing and then select a method of imputing them. In the meantime, you can replace them with the median of each variable.